# Flutter StickyHeader (SliverPinnedHeader) goes under SliverAppBar on scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

When I use StickyHeader or SliverPinnedHeader combined with SliverAppBar, header goes under SliverAppBar. A video is clean an explanatory which shows the "Goalkeeper" is a Text under a StickyHeader. It actually sticks but it sticks just below the status bar. It ignores the SliverAppBar.

I have some workarounds like expanding a SizedBox to SliverAppBar's height. But this kind of solutions are not enough for me. I'd like to know the logic behind this behavior and solve it naturally.

```
Scaffold(
    body: NestedScrollView(
  floatHeaderSlivers: false,
  headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return [
      SliverAppBar(
        floating: false,
        pinned: true,
        snap: false,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                "Title",
                style: Get.textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(color: Get.theme.colorScheme.onPrimary),
              ),
            ),
            Press(
              child: Icon(Icons.star, size: 20),
            )
          ],
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(48),
          child: const SizedBox(),
        ),
        expandedHeight: 150,
        flexibleSpace: Stack(
          children: [
            /** ... */
          ],
        ),
      )
    ];
  },
  body: Expanded(
    child: TabBarView(controller: controller.c, children: [
      ListView(
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) StickyHeader(header: Text("Header"), content: Text("Content"))],
          )
        ],
      ),
      Text("Tab 2"),
      Text("Tab 3"),
    ]),
  ),
))
```

[Video](https://i.imgur.com/iayljcz.mp4)

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan nope. Not a solution as an answer for the question. Still using and improving the workarounds i mentioned in the question.